# Why is the following code not able to listen on broadcast address where as message is successfully being sent to the broadcast address in node.js?

Tags: node.js, websocket, ubuntu-16.04

**When I run this code, I am able to send the message successfully to the broadcast address but there is no output on the message event listener. Same code is working on macOS but not on ubuntu 16.04. I am using node v6.11.1.**

```
var dgram = require('dgram');
var socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

var testMessage = "[hello world] pid: " + process.pid;
var broadcastAddress = '255.255.255.255';
var broadcastPort = 5555;

socket.bind(broadcastPort, '0.0.0.0', function(){
    socket.setBroadcast(true);
});

socket.on("message", function ( data, rinfo ) {
    console.log("Message received from ", rinfo.address, " : ", data.toString());
});

setInterval(function () {
    socket.send(new Buffer(testMessage),
        0,
        testMessage.length,
        broadcastPort,
        broadcastAddress,
        function (err) {
            if (err) console.log(err);

            console.log("Message sent");
        }
    );
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting a lot of precious time, I found out that my firewall was restricting the incoming udp package.